# Making Axios calls with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Basically what I wanted to do was to stop making axios calls inside of my component. So I thought; “Why not just create an action for that?”

I googled around to find a good “guide” to use Redux and this is what I’m using:

1. Add a constant to the constants file. Something like const GREAT_COURSE = GREAT_COURSE
2. Add an action creator to the actions folder. Return an action JavaScript object with a type of the constant you created.
3. Add a reducer to the reducers folder that handles this action creator.

So I began to create my action creator:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { CUSTOMER_FETCH } from './types'
import settings from '../settings'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export const customers = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('http://hejhej/customers').then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: CUSTOMER_FETCH,
        data: res.data
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And later to add a reducer that handles my action creator:

```
import { CUSTOMER_FETCH } from '../actions/types'

const initial = []

const customer = action => {
  return {
    data: action.data
  }
}

const customers = (state = initial, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CUSTOMER_FETCH:
      customers = [...state, customer(action)]
      console.log('customers as state', customers)
      return customers

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default customers
```

And inside of my component I'm importing it:

`import { customers } from '../../actions/customersAction'`

And later using `connect`: `export default connect(null, { customers })(Events)`

And finally I'm using it inside of my component:

```
customers() {
  this.props.customers(this.state.data)
}
```

So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, because I can't see my console.log in my dev tools. Thanks a lot for reading!

#### Inside of my component atm:

```
axios.get('http://hejhej/customers').then(res => {
  this.setState({
    res,
    customer: res.data
  })
})
```

Comment: the axios can get the result successfully?

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi I'm not sure, my console.logs aren't showing in my console.

Comment: so put a console.log before call the dispatch in THEN result.

Comment: Alright, I added a console.log before `return dispatch` and nothing got outputed in the console. :(

Comment: So you axios.get isn't getting a result. You have to make a call to a valid url with a valid return, so your dispatch will be fired.

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi do you know why it's not getting called?

Comment: probably it's called, but isn't getting a result

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi the url is valid, and inside of component I'm doing that (look at the updated question). I just wan to put my get request inside of an action, because I've heard that having requests inside of a component is bad practise.